# Displayed text in HTML is more left in IE than FireFox?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

In IE, the 'title1' and 'title2' are aligned more to the left than they are in FireFox? Can anyone see from the below code, why this is? It's important I have them at exactly the same points because the next elements require for them to be align (so the user can make sense of the displayed information!)

```
<div class='container' style='width:100%; height: auto; padding:0;'>

<div class='title1' style='padding:0; float:left; width: 150px; margin-left: 270px;'>title1
</div>

<div class='title2' style='float:left; width: 150px;'>title2
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Looks like there's a type after `width:100%`. Probably not the issue, but just in case.

Comment: yes just noticed it. doesn't make a difference, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE's "box-model" is much different than that other browsers so it could be a number of things including just that IE's default padding, margins, etc are different.

I'd use some sort of CSS resets. This will most likely fix your problem. *Most* issues i have with that are fixed when i use CSS resets.

I'd suggest adding (from http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded):

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}
```

If it still doesn't make it work it's probably something else on the page, and maybe give us more code to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a doctype? Without one, you are in quirks mode and IE will not attempt to perform like all the other far more modern browsers.

Comment: Also, adding on to this answer, if you DO have a DOCTYPE is it correct and/or is there a blank space at the top of your HTML file? There can't be ANY whitespace on the first line for IE, it HAS to be the DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0):

It the content TABULAR?

I ask because, though tables aren't to be used for layout of sites, if the data makes sense as a table, you should use tables.

You mentioned the content following wouldn't make sense without the alignment. A table might be your solution.